# How do I arrange the elements of my flex box into this pattern using css

Tags: css, flexbox

[How I want my elements arranged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szfv5.png)

[this just made all the elements go side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWXz5.png)

Comment: There are (3) boxes there - the container, the box containing the rows of articles, and finally the aside. That should help you get started. The container has (2) columns, the articles has (3) rows, and the aside is a single element.

Comment: Have you investigated css grid which is more suited to 2d layouts. And please show us your code so far see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: flex` alone will not do what you want. You should refer to a flexbox tutorial.

You could wrap the three vertically stacked `article`s in a `div` and use flexbox to align them vertically and the section could be used to align the articles and the `aside` like this:

```css
section {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.articles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

aside {
  height: 100%
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="articles">
    <article id="1"></article>
    <article id="2"></article>
    <article id="3"></article>
  </div>
  <aside></aside>
</section>
```

Note the `border`s and `background-color`s are just to visualise the sections.

The `flex-grow` allows the articles to expand to fill in the space according to a ratio. In this case, by setting it to `1` they expand to 100% of the remaining space, making there only a need to specify the width of the `aside`.